# Ampersand before a scope resolution operator in php

Tags: php, scope-resolution

Hello I am here to ask you a question about php. I had searched many times on web to get a solution, but I haven't found it yet. I have seen a code like this:

```
$mail_object        =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
$mail_result        = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $email_msg);
```

I just need to the the use of ampersand symbol before the `Mail::factory`.

Comment: havnt found any solution from that link ?

Comment: is it a bitwise and ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference), `=&` is the *assignment by reference* operator:

> Assignment by reference is also supported, using the `$var = &$othervar;` syntax. Assignment by reference means that both variables end up pointing at the same data, and nothing is copied anywhere.